# Thrombotic events and antiphospholipid syndrome

Tags: hematology, platelet-count, bleeding, thrombosis

If my understanding is correct, patients with antiphospholipid syndrome are at increased risk for thrombotic events [1](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/antiphospholipid-syndrome/basics/symptoms/con-20028805) but in the same time, it is possible for these patients to have a thrombocytopenia and therefore increased bleeding risk.

*So my current interrogation is: those person should receive an anticoagulation in the case of a thrombotic event. But what happens if in the same time they have also low platelets? Is anticoagulation still given although this might increase their risk of bleeding?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Antiphospholipid syndrome (APS)** is characterized by the occurrence of venous or arterial thrombosis and/or an adverse pregnancy outcome due to the presence  of antiphospholipid antibodies (aPL) [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=18417261). There are to types of APS: either primary or secondary in the presence of an underlying disease, usually systemic lupus erythematosus (SLE).

**Thrombocytopenia (low platelets)** is frequently observed in APS patients, with an incidence ranging from 22 to 42 percent [2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=18417261). The frequency of thrombocytopenia is higher in SLE-associated APS than in primary APS. According to uptodate [3](http://www.uptodate.com/contents/clinical-manifestations-of-antiphospholipid-syndrome?source=machineLearning&search=antiphospholipid%20syndrome&selectedTitle=3%7E150&sectionRank=2&anchor=H11#H21):

> the degree of thrombocytopenia is usually moderate, with a platelet
>   count usually in the range of 100,000 to 140,000/microL, and is rarely
>   associated with hemorrhagic events. Thrombocytopenia does not preclude
>   the occurrence of thrombotic complications of APS.

Now to your question, here are the recommendations in uptodate *(which is a common source of reference for clinicians, as it provides, uptodate information of guidelines and recommendations)*:

> For patients with thrombocytopenia who develop a thromboembolic event
>   an antithrombotic therapy with **low molecular weight heparin and
>   vitamin K antagonists (goal INR 2.0 to 3.0) should be initiated as in
>   other patients with APS**.